# c# c++ dll files cannot be found

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I imported a project in Visual Studio 2015 from VS2010.that project consisted of one solution in c# and 2 c++ managed dll files which has been compiled in win32.
Now I have imported in VS2015 and I am going to compile it for x64.I did different searches and I did all the possible solutions which I seemed.but  the error CS0246 (the type or namespace could not be found,are you missif a directive or assembly reference?)exists yet.

all the refrences within project have been controlled all the assembly files have been controlled but the mentioned Error exists yet.
 any suggestion will be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: As you don't tell us what is missing (it should be part of the error message), I can only link you to the MSDN page for the error: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7xf6dxs.aspx

Comment: I had read this msdn, thanks so much.but ot could not be helpful for my problem.thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Is that the problem?

> A 64bit executable cannot call a 32bit dll and viceversa. Unless you actually need your application to be 64bit, the simplest option is to set it to target x86. This will still allow it to run on both 32 and 64bit versions of Windows.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/644c2f9c-f06a-496a-b497-6420a7919fdb/64-bit-app-calling-32-bit-dll?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: yes, but I did that..it does not work.the target is set on x86.